# Why is the close looped model under control called plant?

Tags: control-systems, pid

I am not sure if the question even belongs here. Please correct me if it is out of context.

Consider a closed feedback loop.
[image]

Usually, we say that $K^L(s)$ is a controller over the plat $G(s)$. Is there any reason it is called a plat?

The controlled system may be a car with cruise control, an actual plant, or even the famous F15. These are not necessarily plants. Was the theory originating from real plants and factories?

I am looking for something anchored in resources and not an intuitive explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard that the word comes from "plant" as in "steam plant".  But I don't know of any historical research that's been done to pin down the term.

I did just check my copy of "On Governors" by James Clerk Maxwell himself (that guy got around).  At least in 1868, Maxwell wasn't using the word "plant" for "thing being controlled".

Answer (score 1):

"Plant" doesn't only refer to the living thing that has chlorophyll; it, in the context of control, refers to a technical system with in and output – some production line, a whole [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory), a nuclear power plant.

As such, there's nothing more intuitive than the word itself: a plant is what is being controlled.

Comment: I am familiar with the translation for the word plant and the intuition you gave is my intuition as well. A system under a control loop could be a car (not a plant in this case). I am looking for the origin of the name and not an intuitive explanation.

Comment: hm, for me, a car *is* a plant, because it's a technical system transforming a physical input into physical output. But if you're actually looking for the etymology of that word, maybe the "english (anglistics)" stackexchange sister site is the right place to ask?

Comment: I thought it was but I am not sure due to this being a technical name.

Comment: Ha! Have a look here too: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/522825/what-is-meant-by-plant-in-control-system/522836?noredirect=1#comment1345054_522836